# Which class in Netty framework is responsible for sending and receiving bytes though socket address?

Tags: netty

Just started doing code walk on Netty Framework and trying to find the logical starting point of this framework, kindly help.

Which class in JBOSS Netty framework is responsible for sending and receiving bytes though socket address, how a channel pipeline is attached to that to bring Asynchronous I/O mode?

Comment: https://netty.io/Documentation/WebHome

Answer (score 1):

For Netty 3.6, `AbstractNioSelector` (and its subclasses) and `AbstractNioChannelSink` (and its subclasses) are good starting points.

For Netty 4, start from `NioEventLoop` and `NioSocketChannel` and climb up the class hierarchy.

Comment: You can't get a much more authoritative answer than this!